# Running out of memory when trying to use df.idxmax

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a dataframe with 49700 rows and 790 columns. I am trying to get for each row what is the column which has maximum value. Below is my code:

```
df['Max'] = df.idxmax(axis = 1)
```

I am getting a Memory error. Is there a way how can I address this issue.

Comment: Are you sure this line gives the memory error? This function should have a relatively low memory overhead. Also the entire dataframe should be 350-400 mb, so I would reckon something else is involved in the memory error.

Comment: What are the types of your columns?

Comment: @chrisb columns are of long datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on a 32bit System? I have also memory problems with dataframe operations on my 32bit System. The dataframe contains a csv-file with ~350mb.

My script works with multiple dataframes so the workaround for me was to remove some other dataframes from memory before this dataframe operation.
I did it by setting the other dataframe to "None".